structure size difference on windows 64bit with bit fields when compiled with msvc
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct abc
{
    unsigned int  flags2:14;  
    unsigned int  three:2;
    unsigned short flags1;
} abc_t;

int main()
{
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(abc_t));
}

I have compiled the above code using x64 msvc v19.latest on an online compiler platform and the return value was 8.
The same code returned 4 when compiled with x86-64 gcc 14.2 on the same platform.
Can someone explain why?

unsigned int  flags2 and three take 4 bytes ( size of int) even if you not use all 32 bites. even if you use only 1 bit and 1 field flags2 (remove three) - you got 8 byte size struct. if you want 4 byte size - replace unsigned int to unsigned short
